# Nested List of Lists to Single List of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to turn a nested list of lists (number of lists can be 2 lists +) into a single list of tuples.

The list looks something like this:

```
exampleList = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], [1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 20, 30, 40]]
```

And I would like for it to be like this:

```
newList = [('A', 1, 10), ('B', 2, 20), ('C', 3, '30)...]
```

I know that if you do `zip(list1, list2)`, it becomes a list of tuple. But how do I go about doing it for a list of lists?

I tried using the `zip` concept with:

```
test = []
for data in exampleList:
     test.append(zip(data))
```

But it did not work out for me.

Comment: What's your actual expected output? Exactly `newList` but where the elements are lists rather than tuples? What's stopping you from doing something like `newList = [list(e) for e in zip(*exampleList)]`?

Comment: Look at the manual for zip https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip even the parameter list is shown as `*iterable`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> exampleList = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], [1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 20, 30, 40]]
>>> list(zip(*exampleList))
[('A', 1, 10), ('B', 2, 20), ('C', 3, 30), ('D', 4, 40)]
```

Edit:

If you want your output to be a list of lists, instead of a list of tuples,

```
[list(i) for i in zip(*empampleList)]
```

should do the trick

Comment: Didn't the OP already do this and ask for a list of lists instead of a list of tuples? I know it's trivial to do that once you generate the list of tuples (see my comment), but I don't think this answers the question. Admittedly, it's confusing and I may be misreading it.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: I thought OP was trying to `zip` the lists contained within a list. But I'll address your comment as well